# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly. The system cannot find the file SharpSvn.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to do a web page where you can browse through folders. i have done this in separate solution and it all works, but when i tried to integrate it in solution with more then one project who are also referencing PostSharp I get this error:

```
 Unhandled exception (2.1.7.1, 32 bit, CLR 4.0, Release): System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\_projects\...\Libraries\SharpSvn\SharpSvn.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    File name: 'file:///C:\_projects\...\Libraries\SharpSvn\SharpSvn.dll'

       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
       at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.GetSystemModule()
       at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Domain.LoadAssembly(Assembly reflectionAssembly, Boolean lazyLoading)
       at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Domain.GetAssembly(IAssemblyName assemblyName, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
       at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyRefDeclaration.GetAssemblyEnvelope()
       at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.^SgrhoGlQ(AssemblyRefDeclaration _0)
       at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.^+GwnKh4ZYHu3()
       at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.Execute()
       at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
       at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
       at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
       at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation)

    WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
    To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value         [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
    Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
    To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: when i comment this method the error is gone:

static void SVN_SSL_Override(object sender, SharpSvn.Security.SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs e)
         {
             e.AcceptedFailures = e.Failures;
             e.Save = true;
         }

Comment: did you check the target platform of both the projects is same?

Comment: Also make sure that the version of PostSharp being referenced is the same in all of your projects.

Comment: Sudhakar Tillapudi, yes no problem with that.

Comment: Doug, i don't reference PostSharp in problematic project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote: "when i comment this method the error is gone: static void SVN_SSL_Override(object sender, SharpSvn.Security.SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs e) { e.AcceptedFailures = e.Failures; e.Save = true; } "

don't know why but there was the problem so i removed:

client.Authentication.Clear();
client.Authentication.SslServerTrustHandlers += new EventHandler(SVN_SSL_Override);
client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "***");

and this method

static void SVN_SSL_Override(object sender, SharpSvn.Security.SvnSslServerTrustEventArgs e) { e.AcceptedFailures = e.Failures; e.Save = true; } "

and just added:

client.Authentication.UserNamePasswordHandlers += delegate(object obj, SharpSvn.Security.SvnUserNamePasswordEventArgs args)
            {
                args.UserName = "***";
                args.Password = "***";
                args.Save = true;
            };

and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the `SharpSVN` assembly is failing to load because it references a couple of native DLLs (`SharpSvn-DB44-20-win32.dll` and `SharpSvn-Sasl21-23-win32.dll` for the 32-bit version).  If those aren't somewhere in the system search path - which is generally the case for ASP.NET - then `SharpSVN` will probably fail to load.

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088743/mvc4-app-unable-to-load-dll-libmp3lame-32-dll) with one of my NuGet packages not working on MVC websites because the native DLLs were not loading.  Putting them in the `bin` folder of the website was not sufficient, because the `bin` folder is neither on the search path nor is it the application folder.

Try adding the following method to your application class in `Global.asax.cs` file and call it from `Application_Start()`:

```
public static void CheckAddBinPath()
{
    // find path to 'bin' folder
    var binPath = Path.Combine(new string[] { AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin" });
    // get current search path from environment
    var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") ?? "";

    // add 'bin' folder to search path if not already present
    if (!path.Split(Path.PathSeparator).Contains(binPath, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        path = string.Join(Path.PathSeparator.ToString(), new string[] { path, binPath });
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path);
    }
}
```

This will add your `bin` folder to the system search path for your application only, which should allow `SharpSvn` to locate the native DLLs it relies on.  Just make sure that the files are actually there - you might have to copy them from the `SharpSvn` distribution if they're not.

Of course I could be completely off the mark.  Let me know either way.

Comment: will try this and let you know of result.