# Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException: Cannot find the language resource file (dblgen17.dll) when connecting to Sybase SQL Anywhere using .NET

Tags: azure-functions, sybase, sqlanywhere

I am trying to establish a connection to a Sybase database, using *Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere*. Using an SQL Anywhere client works perfect from a workstation, but I am having some trouble running the code within an Azure Function.

This is the beginning of my simple code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere;

namespace SBCTest
{
    public static class SybaseTest
    {
        static string DB_CS_SOURCE = "Host=myIP;UID=myUID;PWD=myPWD;Data Source=myDb;";         static int bulkSize = 5000;

        [FunctionName("SybaseTest")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                var dbSourceCon = new SAConnection()
                dbSourceCon.ConnectionString = DB_CS_SOURCE;
                dbSourceCon.Open();

 //etc... etc...
```

The problem I am facing, which I can't seem to manage is the following error I get when running the app:

```
[Error] System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection' threw an exception. ---> Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException: Cannot find the language resource file (dblgen17.dll).
   at Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAUnmanagedDll..ctor()
   at Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAUnmanagedDll.get_Instance()
   at Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection..ctor()
   at SBCTest.SybaseTest.<Run>d__3.MoveNext()
```

*dblgen17.dll* is included in the *SAP SQL Anywhere Database Client* found *[here](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-35857)*, and has been added to my project, with *Build Action* set to **None**, and *Copy to Output Directory* set to **Copy Always**.

The "missing file" *dblgen17.dll* can be found in */site/wwwroot/bin* after publish, as expected, along with *Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.v4.5.dll*.

Why does it still say that it's missing? My Google results point me to the fact that it might have something to do with the PATH variable, but since this is an Azure Function I'm not sure what to do here.
I also noted an additional, odd behavior, described below.

Sometimes, sporadically when re-publishing a non-altered code, I can also get this error message all of a sudden:

```
[Error] Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException (0x80004005)
at Sap.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection.Open()
at SBCTest.SybaseTest.<Run>d__3.MoveNext()
```

How can I make my code recognize the file, and hopefully connect successfully?

Comment: Were you able to locate a solution?

Comment: @MikeUrnunMSFT Unfortunately not. Seems impossible to do what I want. I will continue to investigate this further though.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it worked out by reseting IIS, this can be done via cmd, with the **iisreset** command.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [the solution that I found](https://auri.net/2015/09/25/custom-dlls-not-loading-in-azure-might-be-a-path-issue-heres-a-fix/) based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088743/mvc4-app-unable-to-load-dll-libmp3lame-32-dll) and it actually worked!

```
/// <summary>
/// Updates PATH variable in hosting instance to allow referring to items in this project's /bin folder.
/// Very helpful with Azure.
/// </summary>
public static void CheckAddBinPath()
{
    // find path to 'bin' folder
    var binPath = Path.Combine(new string[] { AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin" });
    // get current search path from environment
    var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") ?? "";

    // add 'bin' folder to search path if not already present
    if (!path.Split(Path.PathSeparator).Contains(binPath, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        path = string.Join(Path.PathSeparator.ToString(), new string[] { path, binPath });
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path);
    }
}
```

Then in `Application_Start`

```
// Sometimes files aren't loaded properly from bin. Hint to the app to load from /bin, too.
CheckAddBinPath();
```